# Record in Hive is not complete when using Flume's Hive sink

Tags: hive, flume

I want to use Flume to collect data to Hive database.
I have stored the data in the Hive ,but the data is not complete.
I want to inset the record like follows:

```
 1201,Gopal     
 1202,Manisha    
 1203,Masthanvali   
 1204,Kiran    
 1205,Kranthi
```

when I run the Flume ,there is bucket_00000 and bucket_00000_flush_length in the HDFS(`/user/hive/warehouse/test2.db/employee12/delta_0000501_0000600`). (the data base is test2  , the table name is employee12)

when i use " `select * from employee12`",it show as follows:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------

hive> select * from employee12;   
OK

(two line next)
1201    Gopal   
1202            
Time taken: 0.802 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Can anyone help me to find :

- Why it only shows two rows?
- Why the second row only list 1202?

How to setup correct config?

### Flume config:

```
agenthive.sources = spooldirSource
agenthive.channels = memoryChannel
agenthive.sinks = hiveSink

agenthive.sources.spooldirSource.type=spooldir
agenthive.sources.spooldirSource.deserializer=org.apache.flume.sink.solr.morphline.BlobDeserializer$Builder
agenthive.sources.spooldirSource.spoolDir=/home/flume/flume_test_home/spooldir


agenthive.sources.spooldirSource.channels=memoryChannel
agenthive.sources.spooldirSource.basenameHeader=true
agenthive.sources.spooldirSource.basenameHeaderKey=basename


agenthive.sinks.hiveSink.type=hive
agenthive.sinks.hiveSink.hive.metastore = thrift://127.0.0.1:9083
agenthive.sinks.hiveSink.hive.database = test2
agenthive.sinks.hiveSink.hive.table = employee12
agenthive.sinks.hiveSink.round = true
agenthive.sinks.hiveSink.roundValue = 10
agenthive.sinks.hiveSink.roundUnit = second
agenthive.sinks.hiveSink.serializer = DELIMITED
agenthive.sinks.hiveSink.serializer.delimiter = ","
agenthive.sinks.hiveSink.serializer.serdeSeparator = ','
agenthive.sinks.hiveSink.serializer.fieldnames =eid,name

agenthive.sinks.hiveSink.channel=memoryChannel    
agenthive.channels.memoryChannel.type=memory
agenthive.channels.memoryChannel.capacity=100
```

---

### Hive create table sentence:

```
create table if not exists employee12 (eid int,name string)
comment 'this is comment' 
clustered by(eid) into 1 buckets 
row format delimited
fields terminated by ',' 
lines terminated by '\n'
stored as orc 
tblproperties('transactional'='true');
```

---

Comment: is anyone have the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use external tables. I found [this](http://henning.kropponline.de/2015/05/19/hivesink-for-flume/) article when working on similar setup.